# Janus server deploy on localhost

Tags: webrtc, janus

I successfully deployed Janus on my machine

Now I want to test demos available in /usr/local/janus/share/janus/demos

My Janus server starts in http://192.168.0.158:8088
What url should I use to access the demos? The official documentation says: Just copy the file it contains in a webserver.

But what is the exact folder where to copy the demos folder

Janus is installed in /usr/local/janus

Answer (score 1):

demos are in the html directory, you can change the server variable of the javascript file of a demo to your janus server address  http://192.168.0.158:8088/janus and open the html file of that demo in a browser